# regular expression match starting clause with end

Tags: python, regex

I want to be able to capture the value of an HTML attribute with a python regexp.
currently I use

```
re.compile( r'=(["\'].*?["\'])', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL )
```

My problem is that I want the regular expression to "remember" whether the attribute started with a single or a double quote.

I found the bug in my current approach with the following attribute

```
href="javascript:foo('bar')"
```

my regex catches

```
"javascript:foo('
```

Comment: This is precisely why you don't parse HTML with regex. There are just too many corner cases. Grab yourself a copy of [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and just do it the right way. I guarantee that it will be easier (seriously).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the first quote and then use a backreference:

```
r'=((["\']).*?\2)'
```

However, regular expressions are [not the proper approach to parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You should consider using a DOM parser instead.

Comment: I just wanted to highlightthe don't do it in the answer. *Don't do it*. Every time someone tries to parse HTML (or worse: XML) with a regular expression some SO users kill a puppy!

Answer (score 1):

The following would be more efficient in theory:

```
regex = r'"[^"]*"|\'[^']*\''
```

For the reference, here's Jeffrey Friedl's [expression](http://regex.info/dlisting.cgi?ed=3&id=36481) for  html tags (from the owl book):

```
<              # Opening "<"
  (            #    Any amount of . . . 
     "[^"]*"   #      double-quoted string,
     |         #      or . . . 
     '[^']*'   #      single-quoted string,
     |         #      or . . . 
     [^'">]    #      "other stuff"
  )*           #
>              # Closing ">"
```